# How can I make it so when a specific player hit an entity, it gets an effect?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m doing my server and each person has like a power or some kind and one player when they hit anything that thing gets levitation. I am not sure how to do it, but I'm fine if you tell me it’s too hard or you can’t make it for every entity with every player.

I am not the greatest at command. My version is I am not sure but I know it’s the latest I think 1.16.3?

Answer (score 2):

Well the problem here is that you can't make scoreboards for things such as health, or damage dealt in Bedrock Edition (BE), so it's almost impossible.

I can't think of any way you could do this.

Comment: Yea I think ima think of somting else for that person thanks for clarification that it not possible I mean maybe it is idk because command block kinda confusing for me